# How to disable XML item setting

Tags: android, xml, disabled-input

How can I make this item `disabled` setting?

```
<item android:icon="@drawable/outline_settings_black_24" android:id="@id/webapp_settings" android:visible="false" android:orderInCategory="150" android:title="@string/settings" />
```

I tried to add `disabled="true"` but it doesn't work:

```
<item android:icon="@drawable/outline_settings_black_24" android:id="@id/webapp_settings" android:visible="false" android:orderInCategory="150" android:title="@string/settings" disabled="true" />
```

Comment: `android:enabled="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

`MenuItem` have [setEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#setEnabled(boolean)) method and there is also `enabled` attribute in [XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource) (there is no `disabled` option) - check out *Syntax* section for all available atts. you can also use `setVisible` and XML equivalent `visible`